# Extracting numbers via regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, findall

I want to extract numbers from a long string with regular expressions. But i just want numbers with exactly 8 digits. (and no letters in front or at the end of the string) But there could be possibly a leading k.

Please imagine the following example as part in a big string.

```
12345678       ->     i want this number
s12345678t     ->     i dont want this number
1234567        ->     i dont want this number
123456789      ->     i dont want this number
k12345678      ->     i want this number (without the k -> the extracted number is 12345678)
sk12345678     ->     i dont want this number
```

and i want to solve my problem with regular expressions

But i dont have a idea how to do it.

Would be very nice if you could help me.
Thanks!

I tried a lot but it didnt work and i dont get how this with the regular expressions works in my example

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question. To play around with regular expressions there is https://regex101.com (set to Python flavor).

Comment: You can try this, `\bk?(\d{8})\b`, you can check what it matches here https://regex101.com/r/BKmU8N/1. Because I used your code example as is I used word boundary `\b` you can replace this with `^` and `$` if it's just a single value

Comment: So all the strings are like the examples, or can you have "sk12345678 1234567" in a line for example?

Answer (score 2):

As I mean, regex captures the 8 digits in a separate group and allows you to access them separately from the "k".

You can analyze this example:

```
import re

string = "The numbers are 12345678, s12345678t, 1234567, 123456789, k12345678, and sk12345678."

numbers = re.findall(r'\bk?(\d{8})\b', string)

print(numbers)
```

This will output the following list of numbers:

```
['12345678', '12345678']
```

You can also use this regular expression with other programming languages or tools that support regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
\b\d{8}\b|\bk\d{8}\b
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/no7TtX/2)

- `\b\d{8}\b`

  - match 8 digits.
  - `\b` - word boundary

OR:

- `\bk\d{8}\b`

  - match `k` and 8 digits
  - `\b` - word boundary

---

```py
import re

text = """\
12345678       ->     i want this number
s12345678t     ->     i dont want this number
1234567        ->     i dont want this number
123456789      ->     i dont want this number
k12345678      ->     i want this number (without the k -> the extracted number is 12345678)
sk12345678     ->     i dont want this number"""

pat = re.compile(r"\b\d{8}\b|\bk\d{8}\b")

for n in pat.findall(text):
    print(n)
```

Prints:

```
12345678
12345678
12345678
```

Comment: @DaniMesejo There are three matches because there's a valid value in the "comments"

Comment: @AndrejKesely from the question "But i just want numbers with exactly 8 digits. (and no letters in front or at the end of the string) ... except for a possible leading 'k'". If the string was, for example, S12345678 the expression given in this answer would match when it should not

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

string = "12345678 s12345678t 1234567 123456789 k12345678 sk12345678"

# Extract the numbers using the regular expression
numbers = re.findall(r"(?:^|\D)(?<!k)(\d{8})(?!\d)", string)

print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['12345678', '12345678']
```

**Explanation:**

`(?:^|\D)`: This matches the start of the string `(^)` or any non-digit character `(\D)`. This is used to ensure that the number is not preceded by any letters or digits.

`(?<!k)`: This is a negative lookbehind assertion that ensures that the number is not preceded by the letter `"k"`.

`(\d{8})`: This matches exactly 8 digits. The parentheses capture the matched digits so that they can be extracted.

`(?!\d)`: This is a negative lookahead assertion that ensures that the number is not followed by any digits.